# What is the "git suite"?

Tags: git

I've seen this term being used in a couple of places. The [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs) doesn't define this explicitly and there's also no Stack Overflow question answering this so I think it's good to have a source defining this.

I *think* the git suite is a collection of commands and tools you get when you install git. Some of the tools in the git suite are: `git`, `git gui` and `gitk`.

Answer (score 4):

Git commands work in an odd way. Every command, such as `git add` and `git commit`, is actually a distinct tool, `git-add` and `git-commit` and so on. Thus for example if you look carefully you will see that the `git add` documentation page actually is documenting the separate tool `git-add`. And if you look at your Git installation you will *see* all the separate tools it comprises!

Well then, this collection of tools (`git-add`, `git-commit`, and so on) constitutes the suite, i.e, the tools you can access by saying `git` followed by a command name. That syntax *is* `git[1]`. That is why the suite is mentioned at the bottom of every documentation page: `git-add` is said to be

```
Part of the git[1] suite
```

because that's exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation mention suite at the bottom of every page:

> [GIT](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#_git)
>
> Part of the git[1] suite

But without further explanation.
On [download page](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) is more info:

> Git comes with built-in GUI tools for committing (git-gui) and browsing (gitk), but there are several third-party tools for users looking for platform-specific experience.

So **git**, **git-gui** and **gitk** are parts of the git suite.

Comment: "official documentation mention suite only in one place". It turns out it's on the bottom of every page in the docs, eg for [git-add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#_git).

Comment: ["git\[1\] suite" site:git-scm.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22git[1]+suite%22+site:git-scm.com) It's the same thing repeated over 8000 times.  But without further explanation.

Comment: Well, that's the explanation then - these "over 8000" commands are what constitutes the "git suite", and the page for git[1] is the git suite's main page, linking to all the programs that are part of the suite, such as `git-add`, `git-commit`, etc.